# check if requestbody json object is empty or null? then it will throw bad request exception

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-4

How do I Check the request body is null or empty?

for eg:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/my/path/here")
public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> update(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO requestMyDTO){
 .......
}
```

The code above triggers validation in case of " "(which is null) payload but not in case of "{ }" payload.

is there any annotation to do this ? if not how do i achieve this?

Comment: how can you pass ==>  "", you can pass only json

Comment: @pvpkiran yeah we can not pass a null that is what i meant by " "

Answer (score -1):

You can check for expected member variables in your `requestMyDTO`:

```
if (requestMyDTO.getVarA() == null) {
    // throw your exception
}
```

Comment: I do not want to check for each value but rather want to check if the JSON object itself is null.

Comment: "{}" is a JSON. It's just empty, not null.